# Why do the names of neviim change?

Tags: names, navi-prophets, tanach

I was curious why a number of names in Navi- the prophets- seem to change. Yirmiyah is also called Yirmiyahu, Yeshayah/Yeshayahu, etc. and a number of the kings have a similar variation. Is there a reason for this, or a pattern as to which names are used when?

Comment: Tprismic, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question!

Comment: i was once told the reason for the shortened forms in common usage was due to many of the prophets having bad ends, like being killed or leading horrible lives and so we try not to use their actual names in common speech or name our children after them with the full spelling

Answer (score 2):

In the Navi as a rule Yirmiya is called Yirmiyahu, Yeshaya, is called Yeshayahu, etc. Common practice is to use the truncated version is speech. Although I'm not certain that there is really any difference than the way we shorten names bizman hazeh (nowadays), I think it may be due to Aramaic influence/pronunciation.

(A quick glance in the Targum gave a couple examples where the shortened version was used, although this wasn't always the case...and I only looked at a couple of places)

Comment: What about Eliyahu being called Eliya? 

Mal'achi 3:23 (http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2403.htm)

Comment: [Daniel 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3409.htm)? [Jeremiah 28](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1128.htm)?

Comment: @WAF As noted by Rabbi Reuven Margolies in his book Hamikra V'Hamesorah, in the Second Temple period, people stopped using names that ended in Yah-u and only used Ya-h at the end. Thus, Eliyahu became Eliyah.

Comment: @Harel13   I know the Jews at Elephantine used Yahu instead of the full tetragrammaton. Any possibility religious Jews distanced themselves from the Yahu name as a response to this?

Comment: @Aaron anything is possible, although I find it doubtful because the Elephantine Jews aren't mentioned in any traditional Jewish sources. Personally, I thought it was a social phenomenon that reflected the lower spiritual level of that period (end of prophecy, lack of national freedom, etc).

Comment: @Aaron It's not in Tanach, it's not in the Talmud or any known midrash. No one knew about that place for at least a thousand years. So yes, I'd say they aren't mentioned in any traditional sources. Note that though there's maybe one or two letters from the Yerushalayim leadership preserved there, but when they requested assistance from them to rebuild their own temple, they didn't receive even a letter with a big "no" on it. They were just ignored.

Comment: Is Josephus mentioned in Tanach, Talmud, or any known midrash? I'm guessing the answer is no. But we know from other sources he was known. I feel like Elephantine belongs in this category as well. But I agree with you that Elephantine was typically treated like a Samaritan outpost. Which means "we know you exist, but we want as little to do with you as possible."

Comment: @Harel13 It's worth noting we learn a lot about other characters in Tanakh because of Elephantine documents. We learn more info about Sanballat who is mentioned in Nehemiah for example

Comment: @Aaron I don't know if I'd say they were seen as a Samaritan outpost (they weren't Samaritans, after all), but in any case, my point was not to diminish the significance of the discovery. More to point out that in the eyes of contemporaries, those people in Elephantine were probably not too significant in their eyes (other than being yet another Jewish community in exile).

Comment: @Harel13 Some scholars have argued that they are Samaritans. But yes they identify as Jews as is clear in their letters. But like you said, they were barely tolerated or were ignored by the Temple Leaders. But that didn't stop them from writing directly to the governor of Judah and getting a response. So again, a community that is contact with Temple Leadership, and National Leadership strikes me as a community that is somewhat known.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129929/discussion-between-harel13-and-aaron).